# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate stepDefinitions class

Tags: cucumber

I am trying to run cucumber test written in java.

Everything seems to run fine except after I implement the feature file I start getting this error : cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate stepDefinitions class.

```
 package runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/FeatureFile",
        glue = {"stepDefinitions"}
)

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Project Structure is as follows:

[image]

StepDefinitons class is as follows. First I run the feature file, after which I got methods which I need to implement in the stepDefinitons class.

```
package stepDefinitions;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    public class Steps {

            private static WebDriver driver;
            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

            @Given("^I naviagte to login page$")
            public void i_naviagte_to_login_page() {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\TestingJAR\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
            }

            @When("^I enter username as operqa(\\d+)$")
            public void i_enter_username_as_operqa(String usr) {
                WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
                username.sendKeys(usr);
                username.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
            }

            @When("^I enter password as (\\d+)$")
            public void i_enter_password_as(String pass) {
                WebElement tipoValidacion;
                tipoValidacion =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tipoValidacionDiv\"]/div/div/div/span[3]")));
                tipoValidacion.click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tipoValidacionDiv\"]/div/div/div/span[1]")).click();

                WebElement password;
                password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("password")));
                password.sendKeys(pass);
            }

            @When("^I press Ingresar button$")
            public void i_press_Ingresar_button() {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//BUTTON[@type='submit']")).click();
            }

            @Then("^I should be able to login successfully$")
            public void i_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() {
                 WebElement loginSuccess =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//H1[@class=''][text()='Home']"));
                 Assert.assertEquals(loginSuccess.getText(),"Home");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of the `Steps.java` class? Have you tried to run it without any class in the `stepDefinitions` package? You should get a list of the methods to be implemented.

Comment: Yes I did and it was asking me to implement methods, after which it stops working

Comment: Then you should provide the `Steps.java`. Otherwise no one could guess why it's failing.

Comment: I have added my Steps.java class

Answer (score 3):

The instantiation fails as it's not possible to create a new object of `Steps` with the default constructor.

```
public class Steps {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    ...
```

because `driver` is not yet initialized at `new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)`.

To initialize `driver` you could use a `@Before` (executed before scenario) or `@BeforeStep` (executed before step) annotated method.

Have a look at the related documentation
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#scenario-hooks 
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#step-hooks